# Passing a list to an imported function

Tags: python, python-module

I put the functions from the following program into a module but when I import the module into a separate program and call the functions I get an error (see below). What do I need to do for the functions to run correctly using the module? Any help is much appreciated.

Original Program:

```
def print_m(unprinted, completed):
    while unprinted:
        current = unprinted.pop()
        print("Printing: " + current)
        completed.append(current)

def show_completed(completed):
    print("\nThe following have been printed:")
    for completed_item in completed:
        print(completed_item)

unprinted = ['star', 'sword', 'model']
completed = []

print_m(unprinted, completed)
show_completed(completed)
```

Putting the functions in a module - printing_functions.py:

```
def print_m(unprinted, completed):
    while unprinted:
        current = unprinted.pop()
        print("Printing: " + current)
        completed.append(current)

def show_completed(completed):
    print("\nThe following have been printed:")
    for completed_item in completed:
        print(completed_item)
```

Wrote separate program to import the module:

```
import printing_functions as pf

unprinted = ['star', 'sword', 'model']
completed = []

pf.print_m(unprinted, completed)
pf.show_completed(completed)
```

When I run the program I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'completed' is not defined
```

---

UPDATE:

I used shorter terms in the code above and it DOES appear to work, which makes me more baffled. Posting the original code below.  If the above works, why doesn't the module below work?

```
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_designs):
    """
    Simulate printing each design, until none are left.
    Move each design to completed_models after printing.
    """
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()

         #Simulate creating a 3D print from the design.
        print("Printing model: " + current_design)
        completed_models.append(current_design)

def show_completed_models(completed_models):
    """Show all the models that were printed."""
    print("\nThe following models have been printed:")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)

unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []

print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

---

Module

```
def print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_designs):
    """
    Simulate printing each design, until none are left.
    Move each design to completed_models after printing.
    """
    while unprinted_designs:
        current_design = unprinted_designs.pop()

         #Simulate creating a 3D print from the design.
        print("Printing model: " + current_design)
        completed_models.append(current_design)

def show_completed_models(completed_models):
    """Show all the models that were printed."""
    print("\nThe following models have been printed:")
    for completed_model in completed_models:
        print(completed_model)
```

---

New Program

```
import printing_functions as pf

unprinted_designs = ['iphone case', 'robot pendant', 'dodecahedron']
completed_models = []

pf.print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
pf.show_completed_models(completed_models)
```

---

Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Projects/python_work/8-15_printing_models.py", line 6, in 
    pf.print_models(unprinted_designs, completed_models)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Projects/python_work/printing_functions.py", line 11, in print_models
    completed_models.append(current_design)
NameError: name 'completed_models' is not defined

Comment: As described above, this works fine; I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: Please can you post the whole traceback, not just the last line?

Comment: @Fortunato Thanks for responding. The code I originally posted DOES work, which now has me more baffled. I shorted the terms to make it easier to post which somehow solved the problem.  I went ahead and posted the full program above with entire traceback. I have gone over  it again and again but it still produces an error when I split the functions out into a separate module.

Comment: @Josh I edited my post to include the full traceback and the full code that I was working on. When I abbreviated the terms in my original post it somehow solved my problem but I still can't see how. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found it! The term "completed_design" was entered in the definition of print_models, instead of "completed_models".  Somehow it still ran fine when everything was in one file but when when I copied the functions into a module file it got hung up.

Comment: Great, glad you managed to solve it :)